# Overlay an HTML page with an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, overlay

this is a question about the best way (or least effort of the best ways) to overlay an html page with a form.  Best in this context meaning best user experience whilst meeting the functional requirements.

Let's say I have a page with a short form on it; the user has to enter some financial details.  To assist the user to enter an accurate value for one of the fields there's another, much longer form.  The longer form needs to be displayed only if the user requests the help.

For users without javascript, clicking a link will submit the short form (persisting already filled fields in a session) and the server will respond with the long form. They'll submit the long form and the server will combine the submitted data with the persisted data and serve the short form again - with the fields populated.

For users with javascript I want to overlay the short form page (in a lightbox stylee) with the long form, allow them to populate the long form and then go back to the short form with less round-trips to the server.

Do I:

- Overlay the short form page with an iframe whose target is the long form?
- Request the long form over ajax and stuff it into a div?
- Generate the long form entirely on the client-side?
- Some other wizadry I haven't thought of?

A short explanation of the best mechanism will do me very nicely indeed.  Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are asking users to supply financial information and you are not that familiar with security I would back out of the project immediately.  From your questions regarding best use case of JavaScript if available I am thinking your knowledge of security development is limited at best.  Do not serve, request use of, or suggest any form of client side scripting, most espicially AJAX, if you are working with financial informations.  I think you might need to do some security research or hire a CISSP consultant.

Comment: Ha ha!  Great and helpful comment.  Your powers of deduction are even worse than your ability to comprehend the written word.  The financial information in question is simply that which would be entered into a loans calculator - income, expenditure, that kind of thing.  Nothing too sensitive.  Even if it were, your advice about client-side code and financial info smacks severely of FUD.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Austin - how does ajax / client side scripting /AJAX change the security on a web page?

Comment: @James Westgate read this: http://mailmarkup.org/Security_Solution.pdf

Comment: Im sorry but I cant agree with this paper you have written, unless I misunderstand some of the points you are making. I currently see 2 flaws: 1. You maintain that javascript on the client is unsecure but surely javascript (therefore AJAX) is sandboxed. (I would agree however vv flash, activex etc) 2. Same origin policy - surely we can trust the script we recieve from a domain and as long as the ajax request remains in that domain there shouldnt be a problem. Again a good browser will notify you if you are going cross domain.

Comment: @Austin
"all client-side scripting must be considered potentially malicious even if it is supplied from a trusted source..."

True enough.

"Client-side scripting must be abandoned in all forms."

Security could be improved in user-agents, sure, but client-side scripting isn't going away.  SAFE just doesn't cut it either.

Comment: @jah I agree, but only because people generally do not want security.  If they wanted security then they would primarily work to make their code secure, which is not want many developers want.  They want usability first without regard for security.  In such cases security is an optional wish list item that gets tacked on at the end, which is not really security at all.

Comment: @James Westgate 1) AJAX is not sandboxed in any way.  The only security applied to JavaScript is the same origin concept, which does not apply to XMLHttpRequest, therefore AJAX has no security model.  There is no difference with Flash, since Flash uses ActionScript that is essentially JavaScript.  The only difference between Flash and JavaScript is that Flash is compiled.  2) AJAX has no security model and there is no way to guarantee that it will not be used maliciously or as a beacon to unqualified third parties.  The only notifications I have seen are in Firebug and are not errors.

Comment: @jah I may not be right, but so far nobody else has proposed a solution to the security problem.  Either accept my solution or provide a better one.

Comment: @Austin. I don't agree with you. You cant enumerate a user's files with javascript - period. Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: @James Westgate I do not understand what you mean by enumerating a user's files with JavaScript.

Comment: @Austin. Accessing the file system on the client. In essence, going outside the sandbox.

Comment: @James Westgate Programmatic code must have access to a client file system only outside a network interface.  This is perhaps the greatest cause of concern with ActiveX.  I should have specifically addressed this concern directly in my paper.  Sounds like time for an update.

Comment: @Austin. 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem. No access via javascript. 2. http://blog.chromium.org/2008/10/new-approach-to-browser-security-google.html. Sandboxing browser.

Comment: @James Westgate Your first link is entirely irrelevant unless you are confusing JavaScript for Java.  The technology mentioned looks like a security disaster.  The Chrome Sandbox is definitely a move in the right direction, but it is not a technology standard and has limitations.  Still it is a great idea, but I like the proxy method used by Opera Mini better.  The idea would be a combination of the two, but even still it is only a proactive mitigation and not a solution.  "The Rule" mentioned in my paper still stands.  If security were prime the rule would be obeyed first and always.

Comment: @Austin. I'm going to have to disagree with you. Good luck with your paper.

Comment: "The only security applied to JavaScript is the same origin concept, which does not apply to XMLHttpRequest, therefore AJAX has no security model." -- SO _does_ apply to XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be thinking about option #2.

When the user asks for help, load the help-form dynamically into a div that you can pretty up with a lightbox of sliding drawer effect or whatever.

If possible, I'd do all the processing of the long form on the client side, and use the results to dynamically update the short form.

Comment: If the large form is to display when JavaScript is disabled how could AJAX be a solution?

Comment: Obviously javascript is not the solution when javascript is off.  See OP's third paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, timdev.  So it would be an XHR which would retrieve just the `<form>` element and its contents?  Doing all the processing for the long form on the client-side is indeed the plan.

Comment: That's basically what I would do, yeah.  `$('#formdiv').load('/form.html');` or some variation (assuming jQuery here)

Comment: Thanks again timdev - this is the way I'll go!  I was going to ask whether /form.html in your example can be a code fragment - not an entire html page, but Chris' example cleared-up that little query very nicely since I could see that the XHR request returned a code fragment.

Comment: Right.  You can do it either way.  form.html could contain just the form, or it could be the page that non-js-enabled users get to fill out, and you just pull the form element out.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) for this kind of stuff it's really good.

You can specify the content inline or via another URL (which is what I do).  It's probably better to use this second method as it keeps your webpage a lot cleaner and only requests the form content if required.  It also means you can post back to that form itself (via AJAX if required) keeping the whole experience cleaner

Check it out [here](http://www.easyfreesmileys.com/get-smiley/697.html) - click "Tag this smiley".  The form is taken from a remote URL and posted back to it inside the form using jQuery.  It's obviously a simple version of what you want but works, and looks, really nice.

For your scenario where you want a decent fallback for users without javascript I would have the form on the webpage but hidden via javascript, then use Colorbox to load use that content for the popup when required.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Colorbox may or may not be overkill for this project, but the mode of operation is exactly what I'm after - requesting content to fill an overlay.  Your example helped me to understand that the requested content doesn't need to be a whole page.