# How can i create a local file using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

The problem is, i want to save a text file (or anything) in the local system using javascript.

Comment: javascript does not have access to the file system. This is not possible.

Comment: Indeed, but you can store data through other means. Is it just arbitrary data you'd want to store, or do you actually need a file somewhere?

Comment: like once the user have completed writing in an input box in the page, i want to give them the option to save as text file.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Comment: @Amir Raminfar, you're incorrect actually. Some browsers have a filesystem API, however most require that the page be loaded from a `file://` path to use it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to the user's file system. But you initiate a file download that the user can then save wherever they'd like.

In PHP, you can just use

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt'); 
echo('File contents');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical real world way to create a local file.  However if you want to to just store data locally then try these two methods.

The old way:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

The new way:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Alternatively, you could create a file with php and serve it out to the user.