# An update on the status of filesystem access for JS

Tags: javascript, html, tiddlywiki, filesystem-access

With newly implemented and/or proposed HTML5 APIs, does the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem) change at all?

I guess if my question needs to be freestanding, then it is this:  Is it currently, or will it be in the near future, possible to craft something such as TiddlyWiki in a single pure, plugin-less HTML file that is meant to be carried from place to place on a thumb drive and opened in different instances of different browsers but that will still write back out to itself and persist in changes that are made from within the UI that it provides?

IE, will the thumb-drive usecase for TiddlyWiki have to forever resort to nonstandard and/or java/flash applets for persistence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. HTML 5 APIs for accessing the file system depend on the file being selected with a file input. HTML 5 APIs for local storage store data in a sandbox, outside the file (but associated with its URI) and are not portable between browsers/systems.

Comment: Anything on the horizon though?