# direct access to a certain drive,folder and file using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access a specific file through javascript without the use of filechooser?

Let's say I want to read this file: `C:\Users\...\aa.txt` directly into a variable, without a filechooser.

If this isn't possible, what's the best way to do so?

Comment: No. That would bring serious security flaws. Best way to do it IS a file chooser...

Comment: What is the situation you are in? If you are in a website, not a locally hosted one, then no, this is not possible. Otherwise, sorry, you have to use a file chooser, it is the best and only way.

Comment: @BenM that's an answer if you ask me. 'No' may be too brief, but it's emphatic and important. Other people will ask this question and should see this as a firm response rather than a comment.

Comment: @Barney, thanks. I have expanded my comment a little, and added it as a comment.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem it might prove helpful

Comment: Is it web page or XUL application or HTA? There are many ways to read file system with JavaScript, but no way from a browser (except IE with disabled security)

Comment: @core1024,i just used 'IE with disabled security',because it's a local file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (thankfully). There would be serious security flaws in allowing a client-side script full access to a user's file system.

The only way to achieve this (on a website) is through a standard `file` input.

Comment: On a web page it is possible with drag and drop ;) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Only for browsers that support that (~80%).

Comment: @core1024 that creates a local filesystem within the browser — it can't read from, write to or specify areas of the host's pre-existing filesystem. Even then, [Mozilla have made an executive decision not to implement this functionality for security reasons](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/), and it's bleeding edge stuff, flakily implemented by a minority (the demo you linked to breaks on my Chrome, [the only desktop browser to currently support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem)) — a [W3 draft](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html).

Comment: I was talking about the `window.File` API (http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi), which *is* supported by all current browsers. Of course you can always fall back to `<input type="file"/>` if the browser does not support it ;)