# Is it possible to upload and store an image to a directory using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can you store images to a local app directory `img/airports/<image.jpg>` using only angular, html, javascript/jQuery?  if so, whats the best method to not only upload the image but also push the path to the json file upon ng-submit?

I am not using a proper DataBase(MongoDB) nor a backend framework(expressJS), I'm Using Yeoman's angular-generator.  In the end, I'm trying to create a very basic cms, which communicates via JSON.  So I need to store the image and push a JSON object to a model called Airports. All my data is stored in a factoryService which stored as a set of JSON objects, with exception of course to the image.

```
angApp.factory("Airports", function() {
    var Airports = {};
    Airports.detail = {
        "JFK": {
          "slug": "JFK",
          "name": "John F Kennedy",
          "img": "img/airports/jfk.jpg",
          "section": [
            {
                "sectionTitle" : "About",
                "copy": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique, purus euismod tincidunt "
            },
            {
                "sectionTitle" : "Learn more",
                "copy": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 222"

            }
          ]
        }

      };


    return Airports;
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("ang6App")
   .controller("AirportsCtrl", function ($scope, Airports) {

    $scope.airports = Airports;


  });
```

I've learned to post everything through ng-model and input fields expect file uploads.  There are a lot of questions on stackoverflow on adding upload buttons and how to store files using express and angular  but they assume a lot for a novice.  Also, I'm sure i've completely botched the grammar/nomenclature/syntax of angular, so if you could correct me, I wont make the mistakes again.

Comment: It's basically a duplicate of [Can javascript access a filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem).

Comment: Yeah it is i found an answer will be posting it upon finishing.  On using HTML5 Filesystem