# How to store data cross-browser on user's machine?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**Problem:**

User has N browsers installed. As an application I want to store a data shared between all installed browsers.

Requirements:

- Support IE9

Possible solution for now: WebSQL using polyfill.

Any another suggestions?

Comment: Unless you use something like Flash, you will be out of luck.

Comment: To closevoter: This question is not asking for a library recommendation. It is asking how to do this, in any way possible.

Comment: Store it on the server and retrieve it for each client when the user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5 and some of the new JS APIs, there might be a few options.

The newish [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) supports [everything but IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem), you can fill in IE9 support using ActiveX or Java, which ought to do the trick. Because of the sandboxing, this may not immediately allow the browsers to completely interoperate.

If taking user input is an option, I would suggest having the user select and load their preferences file when the app loads. By opening a native file browse dialog, you allow the user to select whatever file they desire, and can use the file API to load the contents and process them.

You can use a similar technique for saving the data, either saving to the file sandbox or opening a specially-formed link ([the `download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Example.3A_Using_the_download_attribute_to_save_a_canvas_as_a_PNG)) to indicate the browser should save a file. Again, you'll run into IE9 issues that will require ActiveX or Java to fill in.

You can see [an example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) of reading a file from an `<input type="file">`, which is likely your best option. There are also [multiple](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) [libraries](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/) for [file upload](http://filedropjs.org/) (note, I have not personally used any of these).