# HTML form upload actual file instead of shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a web form with type=file input for file upload. However, if the user selects a shortcut in windows, it uploads the shortcut file instead of the actual file (shortcut target).

It is possible to detect that the user has selected shortcut - eg. by filename extension "lnk". But how do I (by javascript) automatically upload the target file instead of the shortcut?

Comment: javascript  can't access filesystem, but - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem

Answer (score -1):

```
<form onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
  File: <input type="file" name="my file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];    
function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This code checks file extension. That's not the answer to the question, though. My question is how to upload the actual file which the shortcut points to.

Comment: Downvote is there for "This answer is not useful" cases. That's exactly this case.

Comment: But you are not seeing the Efforts made? :/