# How can i Create Folder file path with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a folder file path just like window folder file path bar with JavaScript and implement the concept in my webpage something like this.

/Root/desktop/users/bin

so when i click on root folder the folders available in the root should be available on the list and when i click the desktop folder the name should appear like this /Root/desktop and so on and when i click on root with current path the folder bar should change to /Root and the content of Root folder should appear

How can i do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript can not access the local file system. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087246/can-javascript-access-a-filesystem

Comment: i am not talking about the local file system ,i am creating the folders in my web page so the path bar should appear depending on click of folders

Comment: Writing a complete guide to simulating a file system seems rather too broad for a Stackoverflow question.

Comment: @ASahra - Do you mean how to create/display a breadcrumb navigation?

Comment: @Fran Yeah Almost implementation of same concept but in breadcrumb i can't go back to the previously opened folders i can't trace back.